# Flash Builder error only in active tab after each build

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I have a problem with Flash Builder 4.7
I get errors each time I build project. These errors disappear after using "Clean" command. Errors are always about implicit coercion of identical classes. Strange thing is that errors always show in my currently active tab.

Examples:
"Implicit coercion of a value of type starling.display:DisplayObject to an unrelated type starling.display:DisplayObject"

"Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:BitmapData to an unrelated type flash.display:BitmapData"

All of them disappear after using Clean. So I don't know what to do, coz now I have to clean project each time I need to run it. And it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Nobody had this kind of error before so I will write how to fix it.

I found somewhere that I need to change external libraries. Insead of using code version I used compiled version of libs. But it didn't help.
I tried to create new workspace but it didn't help.

Finally I had to reinstall Flash Builder, made new workspace and new project from a scratch (I didn't import old project, but rather copied content from old project) and now it's ok.